# Что означает конструкция using static?

Tags: c#, .net, static, импорт

Когда я изучал C# по книге Марка Прайса `C# 9 и .NET 5`, встретил такую фразу:

> <...>
>
> Добавьте оператор для статического импорта класса `System.Console` в начало файла `Program.cs`:
>
> ```cs
> using static System.Console
> ```
>
> <...>

Я не понял что означает `для статического импорта класса`, и решил задать этот вопрос.

Разве нельзя написать так:

```cs
using System.Console
```

Объясните пожалуйста.

Надеюсь всё понятно, если нет, пишите в комментариях.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Разве нельзя написать так:
>
> using System.Console

Если бы вы попробовали написать это и скомпилировать, то сами бы поняли, что так "нельзя написать". Почему нельзя?

Потому что `using` используется для импорта **пространств имен**. Можно написать `using System`, т.к. `System` - это пространство имен. `System.Console` - это **класс**, его нельзя импортировать с помощью директивы `using`.

> Я не понял что означает `для статического импорта класса`

Статический импорт класса - это импорт статических членов класса (+ констант, начиная с C# 7.2). Т.е. написав

```
using static System.Console;
```

вы теперь можете использовать, например, статические методы `WriteLine()`, `ReadLine()` и др. без указания имени класса `Console`.

Пример:

```
using static System.Console;

WriteLine("Hello, world!");
```

Comment: Я предполагал что это нужно для импорта всех статических членов класса. Спасибо.